# How to remove fields that have no value on the additional info page CKAN?

Tags: python, python-3.x, schema, ckan

I'm using ckanext-scheming extension to configure and customize metadata schemas for CKAN. Is it possible to remove fields that do not have a value in additional info view page such as using the

```
display_snippet: null
```

but only in a condition value is none?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.